# Prepros/XAMPP adding unwanted space under last div/footer

Tags: css, flexbox, space, prepros

In spite of setting all margins and padding to 0, I'm suddenly finding that processing my html & css using **Prepros**(also tried with XAMPP), is adding extra (unwanted) space under my last item ie. footer. While running the same html & css directly from Notepad++, does not do this (thankfully). Can someone please explain why this is happening since I will eventually be running from a local host. 
Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf=8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>header</header>
    <div class="wrapper">wrapper1</div>
    <div class="wrapper">wrapper2</div>
    <footer>footer</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
  height: 100vh;
}


header {
  flex: 1;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

footer {
  height: 5%;
  position: absolute:
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Here are images of the same code running, first from file:/// and the other from localhost:

[image]

[image]

Would appreciate any clarification on this matter. NOTE: Above is the discrepancy in every browser i tried it on (Chrome, Firefox and Opera).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you mentionned a **position: absolute;** for the footer. 
You shouldn't, because flex property does not apply anymore on the block.
Try the use flex for each children items, like:

```
header, .wrapper{
  flex: 3;
}

footer{
  flex: 1;
}
```

It works for me.

Comment: thanks, tried this, but still ending up with the same issue

Comment: It's weird. Can I see the code you got now ? (with my solution)

Comment: html: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  <body>
    <header>header</header>
   
   <div class="wrapper">wrapper</div>
   
   <footer>footer</footer>
   
  </body>
 </html>`  css:  `html, body{
border: 2px solid green;
}

body{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column; 
min-height: 100vh; 
}

*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

header, .wrapper{
flex: 3;  
background-color: blue;
border: 2px solid black;
}

footer{
flex: 1;
background-color: orange;
}`

Comment: Alright thanks (next time with a jsfiddle please :) ) Does it give you the exactly same result then ?

Comment: Sorry abt that - will jfiddle next time, it gives the same issue of unwanted space below the footer and outside the body/html. Also the consoler (through Chrome's developer tools) is showing these errors:  1.http://static.cmptch.com/v/lib/abchk.js?p=1&banner_id=23 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT  2. Mixed Content: The page at 'https://static.cmptch.com/v/lib/mng.html?105#180#360' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://trcklion.com/suic?u=3332540220766735691'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.