# Mixed content and empty response console errors only when running on localhost

Tags: console, localhost, adblock

Running even simple html files on **localhost** (as opposed to running from **file:///**) is throwing up console errors on all browsers I've tried (Chrome, Firefox, Opera). I've disable AdBlock and the sytem's Antivirus as well as all extensions in Incognito mode, but it's still throwing the same console errors. Here are the 2 on Chrome:

1. Mixed Content .. the page at 'https://static..' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an  insecure image '' This content should be served over HTTPS
2. Get http://ib.adnxs ... net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE  cks:1

This is how it reads completely: [image]

What do they mean? This issue is also interfering with the output by adding [unwanted extra space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199214/prepros-xampp-adding-unwanted-space-under-last-div-footer) (below the footer and body) in all examples I'm trying out. The issue has held back my project from its next stage. Can anyone throw some light? Note: I am using XAMPP. **Also note, running from file:/// is causing no such issue (ie. no console errors and no output inconsistencies).**

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the problem: Trezaa adware, really pernicious and not picked by the regular adblock. beware. it really interfered with my results. but at least everything's fine now.

Comment: Nasty adware. For future development: 1. never use `file:///` 2. AdBlock on Firefox **WILL** block the connection to blocked ads, based on rules, it is extremely powerful. 3. don't use `localhost` as baseline URL, it is a bad practice: Open notepad **as administrator**, open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add the lines: `127.0.0.1 www.localhost.com` and `::1 www.localhost.com` and `:1 www.localhost.com`. From now use `http://www.localhost.com` as your local webserver (for WAMP, XAMPP or plain APACHE), it follows the rules of a real (generic) world-wide web address.